# VirtualBox Graphics Adapter driver has stopped working (code: 43)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox

So i have been setting up a new windows 10 virtual machine using virtual box for the first time on my new computer and upon the reboot after installing 64bit guest additions i got a really weird graphical error: [image: windows boot error]

but then after about 15 seconds just went completely black before loading into the desktop so i reran the instalation again and the same happened upon reboot! Also, while running the instalation for the last 5 seconds or so the screen goes completely black!Now whenever i boot it says on windows loading screen for an unusualy long time before returning to that weird graphical error and i know the driver is not working as i can't do full screen resolutions! In device manager it says code 43. I am also experiencing weird sound errors where it sometimes stays on loop for ever after finishing? Any help will be much apreciated :)

Comment: Sound was always a problem on VirtualBox running Windows guests the last years (bad quality and stuttering of audio out and audio in). Since about half a year sound is really getting worse so often I disable it as it doesn't work at all or plays the loop you also have encountered.

Comment: Oh ok, do you have any idea whats causing the virtual box graphics to play up when installing all the guest addons or what else i should try to fix it? Do u have a link to install just the graphical driver itself?

Comment: The screen-shot you have posted is nothing unusual, this happen on every Windows 10 guest while booting. Afterwards the screen normalizes fast and Windows login/desktop becomes visible. I only run guests with installed VirtualBox guest tools.

Comment: Ok, thanks for cleaning that up, in device manger it says the VirtualBox graphics adapter has stopped working and says 'code 43'? Can i re-install this particular driver somehow or is the problem else where? Also I know it isn't working as all the main functionalities of the driver for example full screen resolutions in settings are missing